# Why is my label displaying "Your cat is Optional(35) years old" when it should display "Your cat is 35 years old?

Tags: ios, swift, type-conversion, label

Novice in Swift and I'm having a frustrating problem. The program compiles correctly and runs without crashing. The program is supposed to calculate the age of a cat in cat years based user-inputted human years. After pressing the button, however, the result is diplayed with the word "Operator" appended by the cat years which is delimited by parenthesis, i.e., `Optional(35)`. Here is my code:

```
@IBOutlet weak var getHumanYears: UITextField!
@IBOutlet weak var displayCatYears: UILabel!
@IBAction func calculateCatYears(_ sender: Any) 
{
    if let humanYears = getHumanYears.text
    {
        var catYears: Int? = Int(humanYears)
        catYears = catYears! * 7
        let catYearsString: String = String(describing: catYears)

        displayCatYears.text = "Your cat is " + catYearsString + " years old"
    }
}
```

Does anyone know what I'm doing wrong? Thank you for your valuable input!

Comment: You shouldn't use String describing method. Just unwrap your optional and use `String(catYears)`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is here:

```
String(describing: catYears)
```

`catYears` is an `Optional<Int>`, a string that describes an `Optional<Int>` will be in the format of `Optional(<value>)` or `nil`. That's why you get `Optional(35)`.

You need to unwrap `catYears`!

```
String(describing: catYears!)
```

Or, remove `String(describing:)` all together and do:

```
if let humanYearsText = getHumanYears.text, let humanYears = Int(humanYearsText)
{
    let catYears = humanYears * 7
    displayCatYears.text = "Your cat is \(catYears) years old"
}
```

Comment: @LeoDabus Edited, I'm just pointing out where the OP's code went wrong.

Answer (score 1):

As other mentioned, it is because `var catYears: Int? = Int(humanYears)`, thus `catYears` is an optional. And the `String(describing: ...)` for an optional does print `Optional(rawValue)`.

What you want is to make sure you have the value, and not an optional when you print it. If you're 100% certain that you do have a `Int` value in the string, you can do it with `!`.

However, I suggest that you don't use the `!` operator because that will crash your application if there are characters in the textfield.

```
if let text = getHumanYears.text, let humanYears = Int(text)
{
    let catYears = humanYears * 7
    displayCatYears.text = "Your cat is \(catYears) years old"
} else {
    displayCatYears.text = "I don't know!" 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Unwrap `catYearsString`.
Use this
     let catYearsString: String = String(describing: catYear!)
     displayCatYears.text = "Your cat is " + catYearsString + " years old"

**Output:**

Test Code

```
var catYears: Int? = Int(7)
catYears = catYears! * 7
let catYearsString: String = String(describing: catYears!)

print("Your cat is " + catYearsString + " years old")
```

[image]

Comment: `catYearsString` can't be unwrapped... It's not an optional

Comment: @LeoDabus pls check edit answer.